# Как скопировать адрес структуры?

Tags: c#, указатели, ссылки

Привет всем!
Задача простая, в с++ понятно как реализуется. А вот как в C# это сделать, я так и не понял:

Есть набор переменных типа struct.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы каждый элемент массива сылался на 1-у переменную из этого набора. Как это сделать?

Вот примерно как это выглядит в С++:

```
struct STR *a[3];
struct STR d, g, f;
a[0] = &d;
a[1] = &g;
...
```

Comment: Почему именно `struct`?

Comment: Потому что они копируются полностью. Class сам по себе копирует только ссылку. Хммм, может тогда class сделать)

Comment: А, нет, не могу class... Я работаю с Unity, беда именно в том, что struct нужно

Comment: Может быть вы уточните вопрос, переформатировав его в вопрос по Unity и включив нужную информацию? Уверен, есть решение вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак.

В C# структура — это тип-значение, такое же, как константа 5. Вы ведь не можете получить адрес самой константы 5, правильно? При передаче в другой метод значение не не передаётся, а копируется.

Не пытайтесь писать на C# так же, как на C++, это разные языки.